# Drupal - Toggle Visibility of Menu Item Via Custom Permissions

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-navigation

I am currently using Drupal 7 and I am writing a custom code such that users with a certain permission("use business dashboard") should see a menu item in their main menu. The problem is that only I(admin) can see this menu item. I have been able to create a custom permission on the permissions page and have set it to give access to "admin" and my user-specific role and have implemented the following code(nevermind the "xxxxxx" that is inplace of the module name, I would rather keep it anonymous for now, but just know that they are all in place of the machine-readable module name):

```
function xxxxxx_menu(){
$items = array();

$items['xxxxxxx'] = array(
    'title' => 'Business Owner Dashboard',
    'page callback' => '_xxxxxx_page',
    'access arguments' => array('use business dashboard'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
return $items;
}

function xxxxxx_permission(){
    return array(
            'use business dashboard' => array(
            'title' => t('Have access to business dashboard'),
            'description' => t('Allow user to send out SMS messages via         database query forms'),
        ),
    );
}
```

When I log in as my test user which has the role-specific permission of "use business dashboard" I cannot see the menu item. I am sure this is incredibly simple, but I have been Googling and prodding at the code for hours. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Can't figure this out either. Can you try to break down the access callback, if it didn't work, at least it'll give you a tip about what's going on.

Your code can go like this:

```
function xxxxxx_menu(){
$items = array();

$items['xxxxxxx'] = array(
    'title' => 'Business Owner Dashboard',
    'page callback' => '_xxxxxx_page',
    'access callback' => 'my_custom_access_callback',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
return $items;
}

function my_custom_access_callback()
{
    if(user_access('use business dashboard'))
        return TRUE;

    return FALSE;
}
```

Till me if this works... Muhammad.

Comment: Oddly enough all I had to do was change the permission machine-readable name to "use_business_dashboard" and clear cache and it worked!